# Multiplexing 100_000 rps onto a finite number of sockets in Java

Tags: java, linux, sockets, io

I need to be sending lots of requests from one machine to two other machines (100_000 rps to each). I thought it would be wasteful to open a socket for each request (even if I reuse them), instead I think I can use a limited number of sockets and "multiplex" requests onto them. It would be easiest for me to implement it (on the client side) as 1 blocking socket + 2 threads + a worker pool per server: 1 writing thread continuously sends requests in a loop, 1 reader continuously reads from the socket and posts a task to the worker pool to match a response to the request + process it.

Question: Would having > 1 sockets, or > 1 reader/writer threads, or having the socket(s) in non-blocking mode increase throughput? Are there any other deficiencies to this design?

Details: The client is in Java (there's a custom JNI socket implementation translating most calls to linux-specific ones), all machines run on Linux, the servers process requests in under 1 ms, the round-trip takes 1-10 ms most of the time with 2ms avg, but is subject to rare latency spikes during which RTT might become 100ms or more, the link is 1Gbps, requests and responses are 10 to 20 bytes each, the protocol is a simple binary one implemented over TCP; will be happy to provide any other necessary details.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this is the same as uploading a large file, in which case the design described seems fine...

Comment: The problem with this is that all the data still has to be sequentialized on to the wire per socket. The more separate sockets you have, the more independence of what other requests are in progress. *Ergo* you should use as many sockets as possible. Non-blocking mode won't make it any faster, but will make it ten times harder to program correctly.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for the answer! By using non-blocking sockets I meant (but haven't said) that if I do use many sockets (10s to 100s), having twice that many threads will probably become a problem on its own and then I'll have to go non-blocking. I omitted this for brevity, but in fact I have to be sending requests to 2 per client event, but these 2 will be different each time, choosing from the total pool of 10 to 20, so I have to multiply thread count by the pool size really.